# Getting information from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having trouble getting info from my MySQL database.

Here is my code :

```
/********************
* Database Info
********************/

$host = "localhost";
$user = "admin";
$pass = "admin@";
$database = "db_admin";

/********************
* Database connection
********************/

$con = mysqli_connect( $host, $user, $pass, $database );
if (mysqli_connect_errno ()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error ();
}

$result = array();
if (isset($_POST['ID'])) {
    $id = $_POST['ID'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Servers WHERE PID='" .$id. "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
}

print("<pre>".print_r($result,true)."</pre>");
```

**My first question**, Did I use "isset" function currectly?
Because it doesnt seem like it is actually going though the if statement.

The Url I am using is : `#..com/view.php?ID=1`

**My second question**, Did I use the $query correctly?
Because I echo $id and that echoed out a "MySQL Object()"

**Finally**, the `print` printed out `"Array()"`

I'm just starting on PHP, Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

If you're passing the variable in the query string, use $_GET instead of $_POST to retrieve the values.

$result will return an pointer to the recordset, not the rows themselves.  You will have to use mysqli_fetch_array() to fetch the rows.

**ADD:**
If you are sure that you will only have 1 record returning, you can use:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $row['field_name'];
```

More then 1 record?

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $row['field_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ your first question: if you have a input field with the name="ID", then its good.
Please also post your HTML :)

```
$var = 'Hello world';

if(isset($var)){ //If the var $var has been set (in this case it is)
    echo $var;
} else {
    //If $var is not set, then we get in the else
    echo 'The var $var is not set';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is debugging the code with a debugger, you may use [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote), or at least use `var_dump();` to see what happens

```
var_dump($_REQUEST, $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your first question:** It's hard to say if you've used it correctly when you haven't said what you're trying to do. I'm presuming that you only want run the code enclosed in the if-statement if the POST variable 'ID' has been received. If so, yes you've done it correctly.

**Answer to your second question:** I'm presuming on this line you're trying to build a string with a valid MySQL query. You've done that correctly, assuming `$_POST['ID']` is a string (or can be converted to a string, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting).

If you're echoing `$id` and it's returning an object, however, you'll have a problem. You can't combine a string and an object like that. You'd need to iterate the object with a foreach, for example, and extract the id from that. The rest of the code won't work until that part is resolved.

The thing to investigate now is why $_POST['ID'] is returning an object. You'll need to provide the form code at the very least.